# File with 'Protected Operating System File' attribute remains visible

Tags: python

I want the log file for my program to be invisible in File Explorer, even with 'Show hidden files' enabled, so I tried setting the attribute to 'Protected Operating System File' I ran the code shown below and when it appeared not to work, I checked the properties of the log file and found 'S' listed under attributes. That should make it invisible, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
h = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(u'{}\\Users\\{}\\keylog.txt'.format(drive, user), 0x4)
```

BTW I am running this on Windows 10 with Python 3.6.5

Comment: Unless things have changed somewhere between the last time I dealt with this stuff and Windows 10, setting the SYSTEM flag doesn't make the file invisible; there's a separate HIDDEN flag for that.

Comment: Do you have "Hide protected operating system files" checked?

Comment: @user2357112 "Hide protected operating system files" is checked.

Comment: From a quick google, it looks like most code that wants to hide a file does something like [this code](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/src/base/file_util_test.cc#L168) that sets HIDDEN, SYSTEM, and NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED, not just one of them.

Comment: @abarnert Would you know how I can assign both attributes at the same time?

Comment: Yes. They're just bits, so you can `|` them together: `…SetFileAttribtues(path, 0x02 | 0x04 | 0x2000)`. Or you can do the math in your head and `…SetFileAttributes(path, 0x2006)`.

Comment: That was indeed the answer, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was needed was to add the HIDDEN and NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED attributes to the code:

```
h = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(u'{}\\Users\\{}\\keylog.txt'.format(drive, user), 0x02 | 0x04 | 0x2000)
```

Thank you to the commenters that helped solve this.